# Samsung SDS IAM & EMM device enrollment through Google Auth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, samsung-mobile, samsung-knox

When trying to enroll new devices in my Samsung SDS IAM & EMM I get an error when using a google account where my request is denied because it's trying to get an OAuth token through a web-view which google no longer allows. Is there any workaround for this or should I just consider switching email domain providers?

Screenshot of error:
[image]